# Show the charge of an electron?

Tags: statistics, random-variables

> The charge *a* on one electron is too small to measure. However, one can make measurements of the current *I* passing through a detector. If N is the number of electrons passing through the detector in one second, then *I* = *a*N. Assume N is Poisson. Show that the charge on one electron is given by Variance(*I*)/Expected Value(*I*).

---

What I got so far...
since *a* is the charge of 1 electron, we want to solve *a*, where *a* = *I*/N. And $N$ is poisson, and the the pmf of a poisson random variable with rate $\lambda$ is $(1/x!) \lambda^x e^{-\lambda}$. So substituting it in for $N$, now we have $I/\text{(that whole jargon)}$. I'm confused on how to further this to get Variance(*I*)/Expected Value(*I*). (This is an exercise in my intro to stats book in the random variables section, but I'm completely lost on how to reduce this)

Comment: You asked the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3548190/show-the-charge-of-an-electron) yesterday.  In terms of the mean of $N$, what is the mean of $I$?  What is the variance of $I$?

Comment: You should have edited the previous post instead of reposting.

Comment: Calculate the variance of $N$. Hint: Variance$(I) = $Variance$(aN) = a^2 $ Variance$(N)$. And $\langle I \rangle = \langle aN \rangle = a \langle N \rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that for a Poisson-distributed random variable $N$ you have
$$
\operatorname E N = \operatorname{var} N.
$$
So
$$
\frac{\operatorname{var}(aN)}{\operatorname E(aN)} = \frac{a^2\operatorname{var}N}{a\operatorname E N} = a\cdot \frac{\operatorname{var}N}{\operatorname EN} = a.
$$

It doesn't make sense to substitute $\Pr(N=x) = \dfrac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!}$ for $N.$ They're not at all the same thing. The way to use the probability mass function in this problem would be to go through the algebra by which you show that
$$
\operatorname EN = \lambda = \operatorname{var}N.
$$